# How to change the spacing before and after property values in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, text-formatting, default-settings

So in Visual Studio, every time I assign a property to an ASP and/or HTML tag, the double-quotes are placed immediately after the equals sign, like so:  `propertyName =""`

Furthermore, any such tags that are generated by Visual Studio have no space before the equals sign, like so:  `propertyName=""`

---

It is my personal convention to put spacing before and after the equals sign, and I think it looks too jumbled with no spaces.

So how do I change the default formatting to this? -- `propertyName = ""`

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and are you using any addons such as ReSharper?

Comment: Markup by convention does not use spaces around equal signs, probably because older CGI script langagues like sh and perl require it syntactically. Visual studio does not allow you to edit that format rule by default, but you may be able to find an addon/extension that does.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas, that's very interesting about `sh` and `perl` requiring this syntax, as I was wondering if there was a root cause for this in Visual Studio and in the conventions of many programmers' code I've seen as well...

Comment: @BillP3rd -- I'm using Visual Studio 2012, but I've seen this in 2010 as well. I'm not using any addons.